# User defined transformation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, proj, transform

Is it possible to define custom transformations within QGIS, such as for user-defined CRSs? If this cannot be accomplished directly through the graphical user interface, might there be an alternate method? In ArcGIS, for example, you can create your own coordinate transformation, save it as a ***.gtf** file, and it will then appear in the list of available transformations.  Considering that PROJ is the transformation engine used in QGIS, it seems likely that one can define transformations using WKT1, WKT2, or a Proj4 string in a manner similar to that used for user-defined CRSs.

Does anyone have experience with handling custom/user-defined coordinate transformations in QGIS?

Added a `feature request` in **GitHub** on this topic. Link:
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/56753

Comment: QGIS prefers a WKT format to define a custom projection. What have you tried and what was the result?

Comment: I know that it is possible to define a custom projection, but I’m looking for a way to define a custom coordinate/datum transformation. Either by giving in the transformation definition as a WKT or proj4.